# CSS vmin minor deviation

Tags: css, viewport-units

So I have 2 divs one has `height:50vmin` and the other has `border-bottom:50vmin solid #000`. Now these should be the same 'size' though 50% of the time there is a minor deviation between these two, where the one is 320px and the other 320.500px instead. (Issue mostly occurs after maximizing or resizing quickly)

Any ideas on how to get a consistent responsive size here?

CODEPEN
http://codepen.io/LiamMartens/pen/bddrRB

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 I've updated the post with a Pen

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 very much appreciated

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 that's too bad :( I hoped there would be some solution to it. I hope they will fix this in later engine iterations!